# Why Infinite scroll using ajax and jquery.append() crashes IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, append, infinite

I implemented infinite scroll using ajax and `jquery.append()`, using [this tutorial](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/infinite-scrolling-tutorial/). On ajax success, jquery append ten `<li>` elements to `<ul>`.

Scroling works ok (could be faster?) on Chrome and Firefox, but crashes IE after some scrolling. Any suggestions on how to avoid crashing IE, and maybe improve performance?

A `<li>` element contains this:

```
<div class="post_div" align="left">
 <div class="separator_div"></div>
   <table class="post_table" align="left">
     <tr><!--header e.g title-->
    <td class="td_first1"><!--title-->
        Title
    </td>
    <td class="td_second1"><!--blank-->
    </td>
     </tr>

     <tr><!--middle e.g picture-->
    <td  class="td_first2"><!--picture-->
         <img class="img" id="49130" width="480" height="360" src="pic.jpg"></img>
    </td>
          <td class="td_second2"><!--user,text,vote,share-->
         <div class="user_div"><!--avatar+username-->
             <img class="uavatar" src="avatar.jpg"></img>
             <a href="link/user.php?u=2"><span class="user_span">Jon Doe</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div"><!--text-->
        some text....
        </div>
       <div class="vote_div"><!--vote-->
        <table align="left" width="220">
                      3coloumsx2rows table here
                    </table>
       </div>
       <div class="share_div"><!--share-->
        2 iframes here          
       </div>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><!--bottom e.g desc-->
    <td class="td_first3"><!--desc-->
    <div class="desc_div">
             onother text here....
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_second3"><!--time+views-->
    0 views  1 second ago
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your javascript code as well.

One thing to keep in mind is IE fires the 'scroll' event as you are scrolling vs. other browsers that wait until the scroll has ended. The result is whatever you are doing in the 'scroll' event gets executed constantly as you are scrolling, so when you say you are adding 10 LIs you are really adding 100's in a matter of seconds.

The solution to this is set a timeout to execute the ajax request on scroll. If the user keeps scrolling the timeout is cleared and reset. When the user stops scrolling, the timeout completes and calls your ajax request function.

Comment: Where? Not seeing your javascript anywhere?

Comment: Is nothing wrong with my JS . I did what you suggest me, and i thank you for that, but i still had the same problem.After that i replaced infinite scroll and i added li's to ul on click event(click on some button) and i still had problems on IE. The next step was to remove facebook and twitter iframe share(from li's content) and performance improves IE still crash but after many scroll.It's seems that i need to review content of li's.

Comment: We're asking you to post your javascript. We can't help you without seeing your code.